# Text over image, navbar "under" image

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to get the header over the image and the makeshift `navbar`. `z-index` is useless and I've tried so many other things.

**CSS**

```
.text {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 120px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.nav {
  height: 35px;
  width: 900px;
  background: #72a0c1;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 50px;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apendite/Ljp57nrq/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `absolute` instead of `relative` to image class.

Css:

```
.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljp57nrq/1/)**

**Note:** [Post your sample code in SO. Don't post link here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

try to use in css may help you

```
.image {
    position: relative;
}
.text {
    top: 0;
    z-index:1;
}

.nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```